# Correlation between non-central $\chi^2$ and standard Gaussian

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

Is there an analytical result for the correlation between a (non-central) $\chi^2$ distribution (parameters d,λ) and a standard Gaussian?

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, \dots, X_d$ are independent, normally distributed, with unit variances, and $\mathbf E X_i = \mu_i$, then $Y = \sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2$ has non-central $\chi^2$ distribution with parameters $d$ and $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^d \mu_i^2$. If you then ask about the correlation of $X_1$ and $Y$, then this is
$$ \frac{Cov(X_1,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X_1)Var(Y)}} = \frac{Cov(X_1, X_1^2)}{\sqrt{2(d+2\lambda)}} = \frac{\mathbf E X_1^3 - \mathbf E X_1 \mathbf E X_1^2}{\sqrt{2(d+2\lambda)}} = \frac{\mu_1^3+3\mu_1-\mu_1(\mu_1^2+1)}{\sqrt{2(d+2\lambda)}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\mu_1}{\sqrt{d+2\lambda}}.$$ 
Here we used independence of $X_1^2$ and $X_i^2$ for $i\ne1$, formula for the variance of a non-central $\chi^2$ and formulas for the first three moments of $X_1$. In the expression we can't get rid of the parameter $\mu_1$, but if you assumed that $\mu_1 = 0$, then the two variables are apparently uncorrelated (though not independent).